# How to properly bake action for armature

Tags: rigging, export

I just learned bake action with rigacar. I thought it would be the same for rig-ify .I click armature to be baked, go to the last layer (where I think are the def bones not really sure). I select all then - object mode.  I used space bar to bring up search bar and then type bake action, I select everything in the menu except the last one (overwrite bla, bla) then I click bake "pose". I click bake and it bakes animation but when I try to delete any of the other bones that I don't need anymore  the whole armature and character deletes with it..How do I this correctly for sending off animated character to render farms?  Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct layer for selecting deforming bones in Rigify, they all have the "DEF" suffix on their name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update for 3.0 and more info about baking or exporting:

### Baking for exporting

If you are baking deform bones for exporting, it is often better and faster to let the exporter do the baking for you:

Put your rig in a collection (1), select only that collection, then in the export option you can choose to export only the active collection (2), and bake only deform bones (3).

[image: export options]

This procedure saves a lot of time and doesn't impact your rig in your .blend file. In a way, this is a non-destructive procedure.

### Baking manually

If you want to bake manually and destructively, make sure you are in pose mode and have only you Def bones selected.

The layer containing Rigify's deform bones is the last third (1). If you are unsure, enable the display of names (2) and you should see all bones named with a `Def` prefix.

[image: deform layer]

Most likely, you want the baking to be permanent and not impacted by the rig controllers and mechanics. So in the baking options, make sure you're baking into pose data (1), and enable visual keying and clear constraints(2) (perhaps even clear parents depending on what you do afterward, but in which case do remember to always check that option at each export so to keep the exports compatible with each other).

[image: baking options]