# Bake on Export doesn't work as expected when using Rigify

Tags: animation, armature, export, baking, rigify

I have a simple 100 frame animation with the keyframes on the Rigify control rig.

I have a separate "target" armature that copies the locations/rotation of the Rigify ORG bones.

I can select the target armature and manually bake animation frames for it. That works and it exports fine. But, it is tedious and kind of messy in that I have to remove those frames if I want to work with the control rig to make adjustments.

I would like to simply include the baking process during export if possible and have the baked frames not stay. Is that possible?

I tried following the answer under this question: [How to properly bake action for armature](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135618/how-to-properly-bake-action-for-armature?rq=1)

Just by the description of these options it seems like it should work. But, it doesn't. The output with the "export baking" options is just an empty animation. Not sure if I somehow accidentally locked the target rig/bones or something?

Any help would be appreciated!